# PHP: base64_encode didnt decrypt correct *EDIT*

Tags: php, encryption, base64, salt

> *EDITED*

I have an Android project with a login form. I also have some users stored in a DB in a server and i am trying to create a connection, so as to login, with PHP files. My problem is that everytime, even i connect with an already existed user i got `Login credentials are wrong. Please try again!` which is the error message i should take when i try to login with wrong credentials. Somehow it passes the wrong parameters. I have the code below.

The login.php

```
<?php
require_once 'DB_Functions.php';
require_once 'DB_Connect.php';
$db = new DB_Functions();

// json response array
$response = array("error" => FALSE);

if (isset($_POST['email']) && isset($_POST['password'])) {

    // receiving the post params
    $email = $_POST['email'];
    $password = $_POST['password'];

    // get the user by email and password
    $user = $db->getUserByEmailAndPassword($email, $password);

    if ($user != false) {
        // user is found
        $response["error"] = FALSE;
        $response["oid"] = $user["oid"];
        $response["user"]["name"] = $user["name"];
        $response["user"]["surname"] = $user["surname"];
        $response["user"]["country"] = $user["country"];
        $response["user"]["email"] = $user["email"];
        $response["user"]["password"] = $user["password"];
        $response["user"]["salt"] = $user["salt"];
        $response["user"]["telephone"] = $user["telephone"];
        echo json_encode($response);
    } else {
        // user is not found with the credentials
        $response["error"] = TRUE;
        $response["error_msg"] = "Login credentials are wrong. Please try again!";
        echo json_encode($response);
    }
} else {
    // required post params are missing
    $response["error"] = TRUE;
    $response["error_msg"] = "Required parameters email or password are missing!";
    echo json_encode($response);
}
?>
```

And the getUserByEmailAndPassword function on the DB_Functions.php

```
public function getUserByEmailAndPassword($email, $password) {

$stmt = $this->conn->prepare("SELECT * FROM owner WHERE email = ?");
$stmt->bind_param("s", $email);

if ($stmt->execute()) {
    $stmt->bind_result($user['oid'], $user['name'], $user['surname'], $user['country'], $user['email'], $user['password'], $user['salt'], $user['telephone']);
    while ($stmt->fetch()) {
            //printf("%s %s\n", $email, $password);
    }

    $stmt->close();

    // verifying user password
    $salt = $user['salt'];
    $encrypted_password = $user['password'];

    $hash = $this->checkhashSSHA($salt, $password);
    // check for password equality
    if ($encrypted_password == $hash) {
        // user authentication details are correct
        return $user;
    }
} else {
    return NULL;
}
}
```

I also use a base64 encryption. Maybe there is something wrong with the encryption function. Here is my base64_encode function i use it when i store the user. It creates a 10-digit salt and store it to the DB of each user. An example salt is `2b67fd277b`. I know that the proper format of the salt is something like `cRDtpNCeBiql5KOQsKVyrA0sAiA=`. Why am i getting this type of salt?

```
 public function hashSSHA($password) {

    $salt = sha1(rand());
    $salt = substr($salt, 0, 10);
    $encrypted = base64_encode(sha1($password . $salt, true) . $salt);
    $hash = array("salt" => $salt, "encrypted" => $encrypted);
    return $hash;
}
```

And the decode

```
public function checkhashSSHA($salt, $password) {

    $hash = base64_encode(sha1($password . $salt, true) . $salt);

    return $hash;
}
```

Am i missing something here?
Please help, thanks!

Comment: You really shouldn't use your own salts on password hashes and you really should use PHP's [built-in functions](http://jayblanchard.net/proper_password_hashing_with_PHP.html) to handle password security. Make sure you [don't escape passwords](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/79668/login-with-password-hash) or use any other cleansing mechanism on them before hashing. Doing so *changes* the password and causes unnecessary additional coding.

Comment: I do not use my own salts, it is auto generated by a builtin function. I can post them if you want to check

Comment: I have double checked it and i am not escaping the password or change it anywhere. How can i check if the encryption is correct?

Answer (score 0):

Found it! I was using `$password` instead of `$encrypted_password` when i am storing the user, so the decryption cannot be done correctly. Finaly in the DB istead of the real password in the password column, there is an encrypted string.